# migrating to new kubunto server and migrate printers

Tags: printing, migration

Afternoon, i'm new(ish) to Linux and I've tried google

I have a Linux print server running kubuntu, we are changing to a newly built server but i don't want to have to recreate all of the printers on the new server

is there a command i can use to export the printer config from the cups folder so i can import it to the new server?